# docker port mapping error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, red5pro

```
OS: Centos 7
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

I need to map a large range of ports (40000-60000/udp) for RED5Pro server but i always get this error when creating the image:

> ERROR: for red5pro  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
>   ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
>   If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

here is the compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  red5pro:
    build: ./red5pro/
    container_name: red5pro
    ports:
      - "5080:5080"
      - "1935:1935"
      - "8554:8554"
      - "6262:6262"
      - "8081:8081"
      - "40000-60000:40000-60000/udp"
```

and the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libva1 \
    libva-drm1 \
    libva-x11-1 \
    libvdpau1    
WORKDIR /opt/red5pro <br>COPY / /opt/red5pro/
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/opt/red5pro/red5.sh"]
```

Comment: I presume you have already tried bumping the timeout?   "export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120"       Compose authors seem to think these errors are server related.   Constrained server, too slow, too loaded, too busy, too whatever.

Comment: yes, i had increased to COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=600 with no luck, still getting the same error

Comment: @user2105103 could you expand what is meant by `Compose authors seem to think these errors are server related. Constrained server, too slow, too loaded, too busy, too whatever. `

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, what I did was going to the docker icon (upper right corner) and clicked restart, maybe is not the best solution, but it´s the fastest one